# Is there a way to use an already existing Window as StartUp in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm relatively new to WPF and i was tasked to convert an old winforms project into a wpf project.
I am using the function App_Startup as the start for the App and i already created a mainwindow for my GUI. Normally you would just do this in the startup:

```
void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
   MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
   main.Show();
}
```

but this does not work for me because it shows a completely new mainwindow and ignores the one i already made. I understand the issue is that App_Startup happens before the mainwindow and its components even get initialized but there has to be a way i can jump into the mainwindow let it initialize itself and its components and make that the window i start in App_Startup, but I just don't know how to do that.
I'm sorry if this is a really easy to solve problem, but i just don't know how to solve it.
Also i'm sorry if the English sucks it is not my first language. 
Thank you very much for your answers and help in advance.
Greetings from Germany

Edit:
I found my mistake! I accidentally set the whole content to one string and it looked like it created a new Window but it was the same window with overwritten content. ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️
Thank you all for trying to help me, but in the end the problem was very different from what I had written in this question.

Comment: 1. are you in a wpf project 2. if yes, what's in app.xaml?

Comment: @LeiYang 1. yes 2. this `Startup="App_Startup"`

Comment: in app.xaml i've never seen `Startup` section, do you see `StartupUri` as the answers say?

Comment: @LeiYang I have the Startup from this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.startup?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: 'ignores the one i already made' --- what have you already made? if you mean some other window, why not just replace with it in `App_Startup`?

Comment: @LeiYang I already made the Window i want to show with the Visual Studio Designer, but I want to start the Application through Code because i want to control how the window behaves on closing.

Comment: just replace with it in App_Startup

Comment: @LeiYang What do you mean? What should I replace in App_Startup?

Comment: MainWindow class with your another window.

Comment: @LeiYang Thank you very much for trying to help me, but i found the Problem.

Comment: Haha, it's like the best-worst feeling in the world. You find the solution and you are happy, but you get frustrated because it was something "stupid" :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, open your **App.xaml**, then change **StartupUri** to what you need.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

for changing the startup form in WPF projects, open the App.XML file and change the StartupUri String with your new Window.

That should be the trick.

Greetings from Austria ✌